# VisualTree of ItemsPanelTemplate issue - Expression Blend to WPF

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

I've developed a UserControl in Expression Blend 4, based on the ColorSwatchSL sample that comes with Blend. I've used the CircularPanel class that comes with it as it does just what I want. This builds fine in Blend, and I've added the resulting dll to my WPF project.

But, when I try and instantiate the control in WPF, I get this error:

VisualTree of ItemsPanelTemplate must be a single element.

I've seen this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343205/itemspaneltemplate-of-a-listview-throws-apperently-worngly-an-exception) but I'm not really any the wiser- adding the IsItemsHost property didn't make any difference. Does anyone have any suggestions of how to get round this?

Comment: Can you post a simplified version of your code demonstrating the problem?